# Compare a text file line by line with a dynamic variable

Tags: java, string, file, search, text

I have a text file `sample.txt` which have following lines

```
sample1.txt
test.ppt
example.doc
content.pdf
```

I have a dynamic variable called `field` (example `phpcookbook.pdf`,`sample1.txt`) it should compare with each line in `sample.txt` file and if the text file does not contain the `field` it should append to `sample.txt`. I have tried  the following code but it's not working:

```
File insert=new File(sample.txt);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(insert));
String strLine;

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(!strLine.equals(field)) {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(insert, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.append(field);
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

I should get the following output

```
sample1.txt
test.ppt
example.doc
content.pdf
phpcookbook.pdf
```

How to compare a text file line by line with a dynamic variable?

Comment: What do you mean with 'but its not working' ?

Comment: if my field value is sample1.txt it appends to my text file, it is not comparing the lines, it should eliminate the duplicate lines.

Comment: If you want to eliminate duplicate lines, then why not just put each of the lines into a `HashSet<String>`?

Comment: Did you have a look at my example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Commons IO.

See this working example

```
package training;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class TestFile {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static String field = "phpcookbook.pdf";
    private static String fileContent;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        boolean found = false;
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(file);
        for (String line : lines) {
            if (line.equals(field)) {
                found = true;
                break;

            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
            fileContent += "\n" + field;
        }
        FileUtils.write(file, fileContent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, this is what you need:

```
File insert = new File("sample.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(insert));
String strLine;
Boolean hasLine = false;

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(strLine.equals(field)) {
        hasLine = true;
        break;
    }
}

br.close();

if (!hasLine) {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(insert, true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.append(field + "\n"); // assumes field does not already have a newline
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
}
```

Notice the `break;`.  This will discontinue the while loop, since you already have the answer to what you are looking for.

```
Your original code was doing:
for every line:
  Do I equal field?
    Yes: goto next line
    No: append field to file and goto next line
```

But what you WANTED to know was whether or not `field` appeared in the file at all, not in each line.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it is not allowing duplicate values but it is not appending the different value other than the lines of files.

Comment: @user2353439 define "it".  _My code_ is not allowing duplicates, but is also not appending `field`? Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: @user2353439: I've updated my code to include a newline character and flush statement.  That may be causing you issues as well.

Comment: @RussellUhl Your code is working perfectly, i think he is not referring to the right sample.txt file which is getting updated.

Comment: @zerocool: Ahhhh gotcha.  That would do it.  Thanks, Crash Override

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
    File insert = new File("sample.txt");
    boolean isStringPresent = false;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(insert));
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (strLine.equals(field)) {
            isStringPresent = true;
        } 

    }
    if(!isStringPresent) {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(insert, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.append(field);
        bw.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No answer since you ask for Java, but just to illustrate the power of Unix shell tools:

```
v=phpcookbook.pdf
grep $v in.txt
[[ $? -eq 1 ]] && echo $v >> in.txt
```